# Jquery add attr action with element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind, attr

I got a `td` like this:

```
<td id='mytd' style="cursor: pointer" onclick="editLoadInfo(this)">
```

Then in js, I disable it by:

```
$("#mytd").removeAttr('onclick');
```

Then I enable it by:

```
$("#mytd").attr('onclick', 'editLoadInfo(this)');
```

However, when i add `attr`, jquery don't understand `this`. How can do that?

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try with  $("#mytd").attr('onclick', 'editLoadInfo('+$("#mytd")+')');

Comment: looks just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dgw2wyv0/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var el=$("#mytd").get(0);
el.onclick=function(){ editLoadInfo(this); };
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention this is list of td

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable/ enable click event of element using jquery

```
           $("#mytd").bind("click", function () {
                // do code...
           });
            $("#mytd").unbind("click");
```

OR

```
            $("#mytd").on("click", function () {
                // do code...
            });
            $("#mytd").off("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

you dit it wrong cause in your line of code 'this' is string not variable

```
$("#mytd").attr('onclick', 'editLoadInfo(this)');
```

this should look like this

```
$("#mytd").attr('onclick', 'editLoadInfo('+this+')');
```